# Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu hidden and flickering

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, transform

I've looked at other posts, but they appear 3-4 years old, and Bootstrap/Popper has many changes.

I have a menu dropdown in Bootstrap 4 that is inside a container with a transform/translate2d on it.  When the dropdown menu appears, it is below another container on the page (regardless of z-index) and it flickers a bunch as I move the mouse over it.  This occurs in Chrome and Firefox so I think it is related to Bootstrap and their Popper.js use.

**If I remove the transform/translate3d on the big container that the dropdown menu is inside of, things work fine.**

Here is an example; just click the dropdown arrow to see the overlap issue.  Then you an move the mouse over the end of the "Minimum Count" row to see some flickering.  If you comment out this CSS line, it works fine.

```
transform: translate3d(0%, -8px, 0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/paultechguy/mtcbLt5t/30/

Comment: From pics it harder identify the issue, you need to share your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/)

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon. And if in doubt what "complete" means, read this: [mcve]

Comment: Updated with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation, this was an issue with the "stacking context" for browsers.  The Bootstrap 4 / Popper.js dropdown menu does a CSS transform/translate3d and this was the culprit.  To solve, make these CSS changes:

Parent element of the container that has the dropdown menu (this is two up from the dropdown menu):

```
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
```

Then on the container that has the dropdown menu:

```
z-index: 20; /* a value higher then the 10 above */
```

Hope this helps others.